# mySQL Pivot/merge/move rows into columns based on two column ids

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I have a scenario where I am trying to take data from being long to being wide. (using MariaDB 10.2 & HeidiSQL 9.4 on Windows)

Basically, I am trying to get every 'id' to have a single row.

Each 'id" may have one or more 'sqn' (which are always sequential numbers for each ID starting with 1.) I do not always know the max 'sqn' number.

For each id-sqn combination, there are some columns where the value is constant for each 'id'- like 'tpn'

There are others that have different values unique to each 'sqn' for each 'id' - like 'sqft', 'amnt' and 'date'

First is the starting table, the second is where I am trying to get to:

```
╔═════╦═════╦═════╦══════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ id  ║ sqn ║ tpn ║ sqft ║ amnt ║   date  ║
╠═════╬═════╬═════╬══════╬══════╬═════════╣
║  1  ║  1  ║ 821 ║  110 ║  101 ║  1/1/00 ║
║  1  ║  2  ║ 821 ║  150 ║  195 ║    NULL ║
║  2  ║  1  ║ 551 ║ NULL ║   65 ║  6/1/15 ║
║  2  ║  2  ║ 551 ║  900 ║  190 ║  1/1/01 ║
║  2  ║  3  ║ 551 ║  220 ║  110 ║  1/1/05 ║
║  3  ║  1  ║ 821 ║  900 ║   44 ║  7/1/12 ║
╚═════╩═════╩═════╩══════╩══════╩═════════╝


╔═════╦═══════╦══════╦═══════╦════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════
║ id  ║ sqft1 ║ tpn  ║ amnt1 ║ date1  ║ sqft2 ║ amnt2 ║  date2  ║ sqft3... 
╠═════╬═══════╬══════╬═══════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════
║  1  ║  110  ║ 821  ║  101  ║ 1/1/00 ║  150  ║  195  ║    NULL ║  NULL
║  2  ║ NULL  ║ 551  ║   65  ║ 6/1/15 ║  900  ║  190  ║  1/1/01 ║   220
║  3  ║  900  ║ 821  ║   44  ║ 7/1/12 ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║    NULL ║  NULL
╚═════╩═══════╩══════╩═══════╩════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═════════╩═════════
```

Of course, I can just full on manual by taking a peek at each table instance to find the max 'sqn' and then just manually move it in...

But I have hundreds - thousands - of these types of tables that are updated frequently (and I can't change the form of the data I get - I can only consume it, not design it on the front end.) I have tried variants of pivot table suggestions - but when using both 'id' and 'sqn' I get stuck (like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09408/2/4)

Thanks!

Comment: SQL result sets have a fixed number of columns.  Yours seems to have a variable number.  You can try Googling "MySQL dynamic pivot" to give you ideas.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. Half the trip has been trying to figure out exactly what to call what it is I am looking for - or how to search for it. This looks very promising!